# Get data from a table with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Could you please help me obtain the data of the button that is inside that table through Ajax? I have tried, but it has not been possible for me.

I tried with Ajax in many ways, but it has not worked for me. I must bring the button information from one page to another.

That is, I need to get each of the buttons with id `btn-tiquetes`. I appreciate your collaboration, thanks.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.js-nav').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $url = $this.attr('href');

        $.get($url, function(response) {
                var $response = $("<div/>").html(response);

                var $body = $response.find('#records').html();
                var _isLight = $response.find('.table-responsive').hasClass('contenedor-tabla-registros');
      
                console.log($body);
                console.log(_isLight);

                History.pushState({ state:$url }, $title, $url);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contenido" id="contenido">
  <div class="container container-blue">
    <header>
      <h3>Get the info!</h3>
    </header>
    <div id="records">

      <div class="table-responsive contenedor-tabla-registros">
        <table class="tabla-registros table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>departure date</th>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>TypeTravel</th>
              <th>Type Service</th>
              <th>Class Vehicle</th>
              <th>Vehículo</th>
              <th>Path Code</th>
              <th>Chairs Available</th>
              <th>Status Travel</th>
              <th>Status Term</th>
              <th class="latest">actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  03-02-2018 01:40 pm
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-cambiar-fecha-viaje" data-id="45912" data-titulo="22152">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>22152</td>
              <td>Normal</td>
              <td>General</td>
              <td>ULTRA</td>
              <td>1465</td>
              <td title="PATH">RG14</td>
              <td>
                <center>0 / 19</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Active
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados-viaje" data-id="45912" data-titulo="22152">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                        </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Authorized
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados" data-id="45912" data-titulo="22152">
                            <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                                <b>Change</b>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td class="lista ultimo">

                <ul class="acciones">
                  <li class="">
                    <button id="btn-detalle" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="45912" data-fecha="03-02-2018 01:40 pm">
                                        Detail
                                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="ultimo">

                    <button id="btn-sillas-disponibles" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="45912">
                                   Chairs Availables
                                </button>

                  </li>

                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  23-02-2018 08:22 am
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-cambiar-fecha-viaje" data-id="46103" data-titulo="22258">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>22258</td>
              <td>Normal</td>
              <td>Busta</td>
              <td>RALE</td>
              <td>550</td>
              <td title="PATH">P01</td>
              <td>
                <center>27 / 27</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Active
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados-viaje" data-id="46103" data-titulo="22258">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                        </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Authorized
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados" data-id="46103" data-titulo="22258">
                            <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                                <b>Change</b>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td class="lista ultimo">

                <ul class="acciones">
                  <li class="">
                    <button id="btn-tiquetes" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46103" data-fecha="2018-02-23 08:22:00" data-titulo="PATH">
                                    Tick
                                </button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="">
                    <button id="btn-detalle" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46103" data-fecha="23-02-2018 08:22 am">
                                        Detail
                                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="ultimo">

                    <button id="btn-sillas-disponibles" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46103">
                                     Chairs Availables
                                </button>

                  </li>

                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  23-02-2018 07:47 am
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-cambiar-fecha-viaje" data-id="46123" data-titulo="22267">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>22267</td>
              <td>Normal</td>
              <td>Genera Cerr</td>
              <td>HINO</td>
              <td>4056</td>
              <td title="PATH">P14</td>
              <td>
                <center>35 / 35</center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Active
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados-viaje" data-id="46123" data-titulo="22267">
                        <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                            <b>Change</b>
                        </span>
                        </a>
                </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  Authorized
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" id="btn-estados" data-id="46123" data-titulo="22267">
                            <span class="ico editar" style="height: 8px;width: 5px;">
                                <b>Change</b>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                </center>
              </td>

              <td>
                <tr>
                  <ul class="acciones">
                    <li class="">
                      <button id="btn-tiquetes" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46128" data-fecha="2018-02-24 08:29:00" data-titulo="PATH">
                                    Tick
                                </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                      <button id="btn-detalle" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46128" data-fecha="24-02-2018 08:29 am">
                                        Detail
                                    </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="ultimo">

                      <button id="btn-sillas-disponibles" class="btn btn-default btn-azul" data-id="46128">
                                    Chairs Availables
                                </button>

                    </li>

                  </ul>
              </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Start from the basics and learn ajax with many available resources, asking people to code for you isnt the same as asking people to help with errors

Comment: Fix your HTML first, the table is not rendering properly

Comment: The table does not matter much, I just want to be guided a bit, because I have not put styles and all I want is to bring the information of all the buttons that have that id